# could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a] when I tried save entity with Repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, repository, spring-data-jpa

I try use SpringRepository and I have some error.

My Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MB_SUBSCRIBER")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Subscriber {
    public Subscriber() {}
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MB_SUBSCRIBER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MB_SUBSCRIBER_SEQ", sequenceName = "MB_SUBSCRIBER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "dateCreated")
    private Date dateCreated;
    @Column(name = "msisdn")
    private String msisdn;
    @Column(name = "ban")
    private String ban;
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Double amount;
}
```

Repository class

```
public interface SubscriberReposetory extends JpaRepository<Subscriber, Long> {
}
```

And when I tried `Subscriber savedSubscriber = subscriberReposetory.save(subscriber);`

I get error

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException' exception.

could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I use Oracle DB with Sequence

**EDIT**

```
#Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//mydb:1521/mydb
oracle.username=pass
oracle.password=login
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

I think this error because my table not create but a dont know how curectly write configs

Comment: can you show your hibernate config in application.properties. And maybe some more helpful information if possible.

Comment: @Patrick I edit question

Comment: Is any query working? Like Select something?

Comment: not none of the request is not running. and a table is created

Comment: change this part: `spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` and try it again.

Comment: Could you set "show-sql=true"  and check hibernate logs that contains any other select query?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue when forgot to mark my repository class with annotation @Repository.

It should be:

```
@Repository 
public interface SubscriberReposetory extends JpaRepository<Subscriber, Long> { }
```